# Freeze Column in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I know this is been asked a million times and I have done it myself successfully a number of times however better to check than to assume it can't be done in my scenario.

Is it possible to freeze the first detail column where a parent group exists?

I have a parent Group setup which is grouped on 3 columns (in Advanced Mode Row Groups there are 4 columns above the Parent group, the 4th being the first detail row header and 2 static columns between the Group and the Details, the Details being the last column and I have a number of Static Column Groups) and I have right clicked on the Tablix header to view the properties and checked under Row Headers "Keep header visible while scrolling", and it Freezes my 3 columns in my Group only. So now I just want to freeze one more column the first detail column adjacent to the group - is it possible. I have as other posts suggest goto the static column and set the FixedData for scrolling but what Static column, I tried a number of combinations.

I also tried the Fixed Data on the first Column Group however When the "Keep header visible while scrolling is checked it does not compile and when it isn't ticked it freezes vertically and might I add horizontally as well which is just wrong and it scrolls on the first detail column only and not the 3 preceding group columns!!

Comment: It is just a Tablix with a single level of grouping. The grouping happens to be 3 columns but that is immaterial just try with one. Just create yourself a 3 column dataset e.g. 3 Cars - Type: Toyota, Holden, Toyota; LicensePlate: ABC123, DEF456, GHI789 and Colour: White, Grey, Grey then Group on Type and show me how to Freeze on the first 2 columns same as Excel does when you select the 3rd column and choose to freeze panes. When you scroll horizontally the first 2 columns never move.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to make my first detail column a child group of the existing parent column so now I have 2 levels of grouping and details. Should have thought of that!